# Agent interfaces settings in Zabbix for Active agents?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I need to run a ZABBIX setup, where some of my agents is behind firewalls, so the Zabbix server can't connect to the agent.

Every item is setup to be using Zabbix agent (Active) and i got data as expected.

What are the correct to fill-in for "Agent interfaces", for the host?

I have tryed with port 0 but then i got this message: "Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[192.168.1.1]:0]: [4] Interrupted system call" and a trigger saying: "Zabbix agent on Server1 is unreachable for 5 minutes"

/Jacob

Comment: this is a job for zabbix proxy. it can be configured to work in either direction through your firewall

Answer (score 1):

If the agent is deployed active, and the FW allows each agent to connect back to the server on the correct port, you shouldn't have a problem getting alerts.

But if you have several agents behind a FW you should deploy a Zabbix Proxy, as Jacob mentioned.